# How to install a software so that it can be utilized by a home network?

Tags: networking, wamp

How do I install a software so that it can be utilized by a home network?
For example, wampserver?

Comment: How about a computer with Windows HOME SERVER? ;-) Just a guess

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need a machine that is always switched on, connected to your home network.  The operating system you use doesn't significantly matter, it just has to be one that you're comfortable with (and know how to back up and restore with).

Next, you'll need to decide what you want to do and install suitable software.  Unfortunately with such a vague question I'd struggle to provide anything more precise.

---

You've been very vague about what you're trying to achieve, but are looking for precise advice to help you achieve that unspecified result.  If you want help you're going to have to start providing details.

If you're looking for generic advice on accessing MySQL through a web interface then take a look at the archives on the MySQL forum or [here](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/mysqlweb.htm) where you'll find some web based MySQL clients.

Comment: Is there anything else that I would need? The fact is I couldn't run the program that manipulates mysql database on the computer that has no wampserver. That's why I want wampserver to be installed on the network so that all computers in the home network would be able to see the same database.

Comment: for his example the OS would be some version of Windows (by definition, *WAMP* meaning Windows + Apache + Mysql + PHP).  tho LAMP or XAMP (Linux or OSX variants of the same stack) could be used instead.

Comment: Only the M of WAMP is relevant here - you haven't said *how* you want people to be able to see the database and that's key.

Comment: I don't have any idea, can you please tell me what are the methods?